# Вывод данных таблицы умножения в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
max_ = int(input())
for row in range(1, max_ + 1):
    for column in range(1, max_ + 1):
        print(row * column, end='\t')
    print()
```

Объясните пожалуйста почему при добавлении функции print() данные вложенного цикла начинают выводиться по количеству переменной max_ например:
Зададим переменную max_ цифрой 3, получим

```
1   2   3   
2   4   6   
3   6   9
```

если убрать print() то данные выводятся в ряд из за окончания \t

```
1   2   3   2   4   6   3   6   9
```

я новичок, не могу понять почему во вложенном цикле в этом коде не удается вывести данные группами по несколько элементов и нужно применять функцию print ()

Comment: потому что пустой принт печатает перевод строки

Comment: попробуйте так: `print("{} x {} = {}".format(row, column, row * column))`

Comment: @S.Nick как такой формат вывода относится к **таблице** умножения?

Answer (score 2):

Потому что, у функции [print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) по умолчанию аргумент **end** равен `'\n'`.

Вообще, у функции богатые возможности вывода, благодаря такому набору аргументов:

```
print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
```

---

> Объясните пожалуйста почему при добавлении функции print() данные
>   вложенного цикла начинают выводиться по количеству переменной max_
>   если убрать print() то данные выводятся в ряд из за окончания \t

Причина простая -- после каждого произведения, внутри вложенного цикла, добавляется символ `\t`, а когда внутренний цикл завершается после вывода `max_` цифр, `print()` добавляет символ перевода -- `\n`.

Чтобы было наглядно, давайте перехватим вывод в консоль и выведем байтами:

```
import io
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

buf = io.StringIO()

with redirect_stdout(buf):
    max_ = int(input())
    for row in range(1, max_ + 1):
        for column in range(1, max_ + 1):
            print(row * column, end='\t')
        print()

print(buf.getvalue().encode('utf-8'))
```

С `print()` будет:

```
b'1\t2\t3\t\n2\t4\t6\t\n3\t6\t9\t\n'
```

Без:

```
b'1\t2\t3\t2\t4\t6\t3\t6\t9\t'
```